# Diagramming in functional languages

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, diagram

I would like to know if there are some tools and techniques for diagramming in functional languages like Lisp, Clojure, etc.

Something like UML in OOP languages, perhaps?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825675/functional-programming-standard-symbols-diagrams-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sourcegraph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph) for Haskell gives you a graphical rapresentation of Haskell Code.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/Sample_SourceGraph/SourceGraph/SourceGraph.html), there are some examples.